# With IBM's BladeCenter, why am I getting the error "Unable to read VPD for Blade Server"?

Tags: configuration, ibm, bladecenter

I recently bought a used BladeCenter E Chassis and three HS20 Blade Servers. While trying to initially configure the system, the BladeCenter Management Module web interface on the System Status page shows "Unable to read VPD" in the Blade Server status. I've tried to update the Blade Server firmware, but I receive an RS485 fail error.

According to the IBM BladeCenter Deployment Guide v3.1:

> In case of a failed RS485 (remote) flash
>
> 1. Only one blade can be in kernel mode in a chassis at one time.
> 2. The Management Module has known issues if a flash fails. The easiest way to recover is to
>
>    1. Pull the failed blade from the chassis
>    2. Reset the MM
>    3. Reinsert the failed blade
>    4. Retry the flash on the failed blade after the blades have all been discovered.

Even after trying this, I received the RS485 flash failed error and the VPD was still unable to be read.

#### Configuration

- BladeCenter E Chassis --- MTM 8677-2XX
- Blade Server HS20 --- MTM 8843-25U
- BladeCenter Management Module (not the Advanced Management Module) --- FRU P/N 73P9326

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized that even though I bought the used BladeCenter chassis and the used Blade Servers from the same vendors, they weren't necessarily from the same install. This led me to believe that the VPD was not able to be read because the Management Module, which I have an older model, wasn't able to recognize the newer HS20s. After updating the [Management Module firmware with v1.22Q (BRET86Q)](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=migr-65237), I am now able to see the Blade Servers, no longer have the VPD error, and can successfully update the Blade Server firmware.